# SharePoint Design Manager Master Page DIV placement issue

Tags: custom-masterpage, html, design, design-manager, user-experience

I'm troubleshooting a master page customized with Design Manager.

They have a Quicklaunch menu on the right hand side of their content, or rather want it there, BUT it is being pushed to the bottom of the page.

When I'm looking at the Design Manager HTML I can see 'QuickLaunch' DIV is outside of the 'BodyContent' DIV.  However on the live page, the 'QuickLaunch' is being nested inside of the 'BodyContent'.  I've checked and ensured all DIV's up to this point are closed properly, so it seems like something SharePoint is doing to the page.  I need these to be siblings and float the QL against the content.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, or has some tips on figuring this one out?

Snippet of the Design Manager HTML
[image]

Snippet of Rendered HTML

[image]

**UPDATE**

Still have not tracked down the reason it is nesting these DIV's. We ended up wrapping it all in a Table and that has pulled it all together.  It would have been preferable to not use them but, the effort to track this down was far exceeding just putting that in place.

Answer (score 1):

Set width of the div and use css float right and left in the DIV. Hope it helps you.

As you mentioned that both are float left which is wrong **DIV of Quick launch should be left float and DIV of BodyContent should be right**

Comment: BodyContent and Quicklaunch are both floated LEFT.  The problem is Quicklaunch is INSIDE (Child) BodyContent when it should render as a sibling, so the behavior is not as expected. Unfortunately, I am not sure if this is something SharePoint is doing on conversion or if it may be some other errant tag, changing the behavior unexpectedly.